# Can C# implicitly convert a delegate parameter of a generic function?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing a method that given an input and an extractor function processes the input and returns the result. In this simplified example it just throws if the result is null:

```cs
public static TResult Process<TInput, TResult>(TInput input, Func<TInput, TResult?> processor)
    where TResult : struct
{
    return processor(input) ?? throw new Exception();
}

// for later do note that this overload also exist:
public static TResult Process<TInput, TResult>(TInput input, Func<TInput, TResult?> processor)
    where TResult : class
{
    return processor(input) ?? throw new Exception();
}
```

**It cannot be called like this:**

```cs
bool c = Process(false, x => !x); // Error: The type arguments for method 'Program.Process<TResult>(bool, Func<bool, TResult?>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

#### Idea 1:

I found these valid ways to call it:

```cs
Func<bool, bool?> processor = x => !x;
bool a = Process(false, processor);

bool b = Process<bool, bool>(false, x => !x);
```

But these are **too verbose** (the real method's generic parameters that are usually quite complex). Is there a way to make C# pick the right generic parameter and implicitly convert `Func<bool, bool>` to `Func<bool, bool?>`?

#### Idea 2:

Adding an overload for non-nullable returns is not possible because we already have an overload for reference types that it conflicts with:

```cs
public static TResult Process<TInput, TResult>(TInput input, Func<TInput, TResult> processor) // Error: Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Process' with the same parameter types
    where TResult : struct
{
    return processor(input);
}
```

#### Idea 3:

Convert the overload with `class` generic constrain to `notnull` generic constraint. That fixes the original call, but breaks this one:

```cs
bool e = Process(false, x => x ? x : null); // Error: The type arguments for method 'Program.Process<TInput, TResult>(TInput, Func<TInput, TResult?>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

#### Idea 4:

Removing all overloads except one, and removing its generic constraints also doesn't work.

---

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1TRawz

Comment: Why not create simple Process function which accepts both struct/class and decides what to do with them inside? Is it vendor locked? Call it something like ProcessV2 and go on with life. Or create a builder with fluent syntax extensions something like ProcessBuilder<TIn, TOut> which implicitly casts to TOut

Comment: Do you mean no generic constraints? That doesn't work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yGZ7iy 
Or no generics at all? That won't work because TResult becomes many different types, values, simple objects, complex and nested objects... 
No vendor lock at all, the process function is something we will use a lot to unwrap/validate/convert incoming json, and I want the caller's code to be as simple as possible, thus no generic parameters when calling.

Comment: Yeah, I provided example. Added ThrowIfNull for cases where TOut is class? , you can do your own naming/constraints as you see fit, but I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution you're likely to find is your "Idea 3," using `notnull`:

```
public static TResult Process<TInput, TResult>(TInput input, Func<TInput, TResult?> processor)
    where TResult : struct
{
    return processor(input) ?? throw new Exception();
}

public static TResult Process<TInput, TResult>(TInput input, Func<TInput, TResult?> processor)
    where TResult : notnull
{
    return processor(input) ?? throw new Exception();
}
```

The problem you cited with this approach deals with implicit typing, which is more fundamental than generics: there's no way for C# to know that `null` means a null boolean in that expression.

```
var a = true ? true : null;
```

> `CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'bool' and '<null>'`

Since `TInput` and `TResult` are allowed to be different types, you'll need to give the compiler a hint about what type your expression is returning:

```
bool e = Process(false, x => x ? x : (bool?)null);
```

Hopefully that's not too verbose.

Answer (score -2):

You could go full fluent if you are feel restricted by Generics in C# (which most libraries like LINQ,FluentAssertions,etc use). This way you are free to make your own Domain Specific Language:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool c = Process.Object(false).Using(x=> !x);
        //or even chain them
        int garbage = Process
            .Object(false)
            .Using(x => !x)
            .Next(x => x ? "a" : null)
            .ThrowIfNull()
            .Next(x => x[0])
            .Do_A_Barrel_Roll()
            .Do_A_Barrel_Roll()
            .Do_A_Barrel_Roll()
            .Next(x => x & 8); //not null as you see

        bool g = Process
            .Object(false)
            .Using(x => x ? x : (bool?)null)
            .ThrowIfNull(); //not null either
    }
}

public class ProcessorInput<TIn>
{
    public Func<TIn> InputProvider { get; set; }
}

public class Processor<TIn, TOut>
{
    public Func<TIn> InputProvider { get; set; }
    public Func<TIn, TOut> OutputProvider { get; set; }
    
    public static implicit operator TOut(Processor<TIn, TOut> processor)
    {
        return processor.Eval();
    }

    public TOut Eval()
    {
        return OutputProvider(InputProvider());
    }
}

public static class Process
{
    public static ProcessorInput<TIn> Object<TIn>(TIn input)
    {
        return Object(() => input);
    }
    public static ProcessorInput<TIn> Object<TIn>(Func<TIn> inputProvider)
    {
        return new ProcessorInput<TIn>() { InputProvider = inputProvider };
    }
    public static Processor<TIn, TOut> Using<TIn, TOut>(this ProcessorInput<TIn> processorInput, Func<TIn, TOut> outputProvider)
    {
        return new Processor<TIn, TOut>()
            { InputProvider = processorInput.InputProvider, OutputProvider = outputProvider };
    }
    public static Processor<TOut, TNextOut> Next<TIn, TOut, TNextOut>(this Processor<TIn, TOut> processor, Func<TOut, TNextOut> nextOutputProvider)
    {
        return new Processor<TOut, TNextOut>
        {
            InputProvider = processor.Eval,
            OutputProvider = nextOutputProvider
        };
    }

    public static Processor<TIn, TOut> Do_A_Barrel_Roll<TIn, TOut>(this Processor<TIn, TOut> processor)
    {
        return new Processor<TIn, TOut>
        {
            InputProvider = processor.InputProvider,
            OutputProvider = (x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Barrel roll!");
                return processor.OutputProvider(x);
            })
        };
    }
    
    public static Processor<TIn, TOut> ThrowIfNull<TIn, TOut>(this Processor<TIn, TOut?> processor)
        where TOut : class
    {
        return new Processor<TIn, TOut>
        {
            InputProvider = processor.InputProvider,
            OutputProvider = (x => processor.OutputProvider(x) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException())
        };
    }
    
    public static Processor<TIn, TOut> ThrowIfNull<TIn, TOut>(this Processor<TIn, TOut?> processor)
        where TOut : struct
    {
        return new Processor<TIn, TOut>
        {
            InputProvider = processor.InputProvider,
            OutputProvider = (x => processor.OutputProvider(x) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException())
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the additional methods/objects you've created do anything to address the problem here.  Your code only compiles because you removed the constraints and nullability changes to the code, which was both why it wasn't working and makes it not meet the requirements shown.  You can just remove the constraints and references to nullability to get the OP's code to compile as a single method.  But then it behaves differently.

Comment: But......he could do.....ThrowIfNull......fluently.....or practically anything with TOut.....

Comment: Well you didn't make it do what the question was asking for.  If you want to make it do that, then perhaps this could *become* an answer to the question.  As it is this does nothing to solve the actual problem asked, and just adds a ton of complexity that's not adding any value.

Comment: Well, I provided one.

Comment: You didn't provide one for both nullable structs and nullable classes, as mentioned, nor did you change the type of the result, when it's supposed to.  Additionally the OP is specifically requesting this method still be able to accept non-nullable structs and have them be implicitly converted.  This does none of that.

Comment: Finally, I get what he wanted. A conversion to non-nullable.